# Failed to get GUI / graphics Ubuntu 20.04 (Nvidia 2080Ti)

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 20.04

I got a brand new computer with a Nvidia2080Ti. I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 (no other OS on the system). Install seems to work fine (I used safe graphics mode). But after rebooting (and removing USB stick), got a messed-up screen locked on Live-Patch. Can't do anything.... The only clue / message I got is something including "SEV: failed to get status. Error: 0x0" (2 lines).

For now, I am only trying to get ubuntu 20.04 running in graphical mode.

Any help really welcomed (I googled around but I was surprised to not find a direction to look into).

longan

Answer (score 0):

How comes you think that it's graphic card related?

I think you need to update the motherboard first.

I would do:

- Check if installation USB is not corrupted
- Reinstall again.
- Same    Problem? -> Update/Downgrade Motherboard.
- Reinstall again.

I think it's because you PC is new and you obviously didn't update motherboard. :-)

Comment: Thanks will try that. I was assuming it was graphic card because I have no apparent issue with the command line... Not sure how to upgrade motherboard though but I guess it is another question

Comment: Hi, so I did updgrade the BIOS to the latest version (Feb 2020). Re-installed (with GUI working fine) and now, I got a black screen at boot tume... I will dig into booting in command line and try to re-install drivers from there... A good link would be appreciated (or a more direct solution).

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you try [this image](https://sourceforge.net/projects/toysbox/files/bionic-nvidia/ubuntu-20.04-5.4.0-26-generic-nvidia-450.57-primeselect.iso) made by me, which is almost the original focal with latest nvidia drivers installed and with prime-select fully functioning without reboot.

If testing with a live image is ok, you can install on your HDD.

You have to manually add an option `pcie_port_pm=off` to the end of your kernel_cmdline_atboot and also modify your `/etc/default/grub`:

The line beginning `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` should be like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_port_pm=off"
```

And then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

so as to enable real switch off of nvidia gpu card when switching to intel integrated graphics.

If you don't do this you are still able to switch back and forth between intel and nvidia without reboot, but your nvidia gpu remains on all the time. Just some 5-10 W ...more from your battery !!!!

And you have latest nvidia driver on latest Ubuntu.

PS. If you had downloaded the image before 2020aug09 and get stuck at "initramfs with rootfs cannot be found" ,do not throw your usb stick,it's
usable.

Reboot with the stick,at boot prompt menu showing "Try ubuntu without install...." just do

1  type "e"  to edit the "Try ubuntu.." grub's config line

2  Replace "maybe-ubiquity"  with "boot=casper"

3  type "F10"  to boot

that should work .

Comment: People should not install modified versions of Ubuntu from unknown sources!

Comment: Hi hoan, thank you very much for sharing your image. I have edited your post to make it clear that this is your own work. Please do the same in future in accordance with [this policy](https://askubuntu.com/help/promotion).

Comment: Thanks. I did all that. That did not work perfectly. Hower, I managed to use "prime-select nvidia" to start to GUI. That did not help the nvidia driver but that would be another question.